# DocuSign Organization Create/Share Envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign API to create envelopes. I have that working. The application I am writing is being used by an organization, with multiple people needing access to documents created within the organization. Each person accessing the application (and subsequently the DocuSign API) has their own DocuSign account, and has granted permission to the application to use their docusign account.  When I create envelopes via the DocuSign API, I need the documents to be available to be managed by any user setup in the Orgniazation at DocuSign. As it is right now, every documents I create via the API is owned by the user who created the document, other users within the organization can view the envelope/documents if provided a link to navigate directly to at DocuSign, but can't do anything with those documents. Ex: If I create a draft as one user, I want to be able finish/send the draft as another user, and both of these users are part of the same organization.

**Questions:**

1. Can an organization own a document (instead of a user)? and how?
2. How can I share documents between all users within the organization, and allow all those other users permission to edit/manage those documents? The number of documents is constantly changing as multiple employees are creating and editing many documents each day.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question. We're not customer support for [your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find my response for both your queries:

- Can an organization own a document (instead of a user)? and how?

  *Organization can never be the owner of the envelope, it has to be a user only.*
- How can I share documents between all users within the organization,
  and allow all those other users permission to edit/manage those
  documents? The number of documents is constantly changing as multiple
  employees are creating and editing many documents each day.

  *Yes, you can share the envelopes among other users in your DocuSign account. Sharing is enabled and managed by your DocuSign administrator. If your account administrator has enabled sharing for you, you can view and help manage the envelopes that are shared with you. If you are not able to follow the procedures in [this](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-shared-documents) topic, check with your DocuSign account administrator to see if sharing is set up for you.
  DocuSign Account's Admin has to follow steps as explained in [this](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-share-envelopes) link to enable the sharing of the envelopes between different users in the accounts. Once it is correctly set, then you can view envelopes sent from other users in your DocuSign account.*